# AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL when trying to use a user input

Tags: c

here is the code that i have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

const int Win = 0, Lose = 1, Draw = 2;
const int Rock = 0, Paper = 1, Scissors = 2;

int input(int n, char i[n]){
  if (i[0] == 'R' || i[0] == 'r') return Rock;
  else if (i[0] == 'P' || i[0] == 'p') return Paper;
  else if (i[0] == 'S' || i[0] == 's') return Scissors;
  else return -1;
}

int game(int n){
  srand(time(NULL));
  int r = rand() % 2;
  if (r == n) return Draw;
  else if (r == 0 && n == 1) return Win;
  else if (r == 0 && n == 2) return Lose;
  else if (r == 1 && n == 0) return Lose;
  else if (r == 1 && n == 2) return Win;
  else if (r == 2 && n == 0) return Win;
  else if (r == 2 && n == 1) return Lose;
  else return 0;
}

void print(int game){
  if (game == Draw && input == Rock) printf ("i chose rock, its a draw\n");
  else if (game == Draw && input == Paper) printf ("i chose paper, its a draw\n");
  else if (game == Draw && input == Scissors) printf ("i chose scissors, its a draw\n");
  else if (game == Win && input == Rock) printf ("i chose scissors, you win\n");
  else if (game == Win && input == Paper) printf ("i chose rock, you win\n");
  else if (game == Win && input == Scissors) printf ("i chose paper, you win\n");
  else if (game == Lose && input == Rock) printf ("i chose paper, you lose\n");
  else if (game == Lose && input == Paper) printf ("i chose scissors, you lose\n");
  else printf ("i chose rock, you lose\n");
}

// void checkInput(){
//     assert(input(1, 'R') == 1);
//     assert(input(1, 'r') == 1);
//     assert(input(1, 'P') == 2);
//     assert(input(1, 'p') == 2);
//     assert(input(1, 'S') == 3);
//     assert(input(1, 's') == 3);
//     printf("all tests pass\n");
// }

int main(){
  setbuf(stdout, NULL);
  char *j[1];
  for(int a = 0; a >= 0; a++){
    printf("pick rock, paper, scissors (R/P/S) 'e' to exit\n");
    scanf("%s", &*j[0]);
    if (j[0] == 'e') break;
    print(game(input(strlen(j[0]), j[0])));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

when i run it prints out the line and lets me input something after which it gives me this error

```
pick rock, paper, scissors (R/P/S) 'e' to exit
R
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==4029==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7f5ca33d6787 (pc 0x7f5ca328ffdd bp 0x7ffca0431550 sp 0x7ffca0430e70 T0)
==4029==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
    #0 0x7f5ca328ffdc  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x6cfdc)
    #1 0x7f5ca329f12b  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x7c12b)
    #2 0x4a724c  (/home/student/Documents/extra+0x4a724c)
    #3 0x4a734e  (/home/student/Documents/extra+0x4a734e)
    #4 0x512a5e  (/home/student/Documents/extra+0x512a5e)
    #5 0x7f5ca3244b96  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #6 0x419e19  (/home/student/Documents/extra+0x419e19)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x6cfdc) 
==4029==ABORTING
```

how can i stop this from happening as this error means nothing to me, and cant see anything that could be wrong with it. I know i have pasted a lot of code but i figure you need to see all of it to have an idea where it is crashing from.

Comment: How did you compile this code?

Comment: You should include debugging information in the compiled objects and the linked executable — by using the `-g` option with many compilers.  You'd then get better information in the stack backtrace (probably file names and line numbers, maybe function names too), which would make your task easier.  You should also ensure you have all warnings (or most warnings) enabled when you compile so as to head off trouble.

Comment: i used clang -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic name.c -o name to compile

Comment: just saw the makefile we were given also contains -fsanitize=undefined and -fsanitize=address and compiling without that doesnt give the sanitize error, im a retard haha

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn on compiler warnings:  You have some significant problems in your code.

The lines of the form:

```
else if (game == Draw && input == Paper) printf ("i chose paper, its a draw\n");
```

are comparing input (which is a function pointer) to an integer.  The compiler will warn you about this problem if you let it.  Do that, try again, and ask for help if you need it.

Also, you are not using scanf properly.  Look for questions on Stack Overflow about scanf, and print the value you get back from scanf in order to debug your program.

Best of luck, and don't hesitate to ask another question when you get stuck.